# create img and li inside prototype function and append in my ul

Tags: jquery

```
Setup.prototype._toImg = function(fieldStore, url_src, outputFormat, width, height, idImg, classImg){
  this.field = fieldStore;
  this.src = url_src;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.class = classImg;
  this.id = idImg;

    var s = $(this.field);

  var li =$("<li>", {
    class: "productContent__ul__li"
  });

    var img = $("<img/>", {
      src: this.src,
      id: this.id,
      class: this.class,
      width: this.width,
      height: this.height
    }).appendTo(li);

    li.appendTo(s);
}

that._toImg("#productContent__ul", comfirmUrl, "png", 45, 45, null, "comfirm__image");
```

i am using this function to create image to li and li append to my ul , but somehow it wont create the image or the li , i check the ul id is correct and the income data are good noting wrong , so my question is how do i create img and li inside my prototype function ?

```
<div id="formDisplay-productContent">
    <ul id="productContent__ul"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do some simple debugging in your method to narrow down the problem

Comment: Seems to work ok here ~ http://jsfiddle.net/qbfj5q86/. Did you perhaps spell the name of your `comfirmUrl` variable wrong? Should it be `confirmUrl` instead?

Comment: i dont why i check the comfirmUrl , still cant.